# what media rule should i add to make site responsive?

Tags: responsive-design

I am building a website in **wordpress** so i selected the responsive theme ,
& increased the width of page by adding css
 `.container {
width: 1340px;
}`

now my site becomes unresponsive , any solution for it?
Thanks
website - http://cardmart.tk

Comment: Any reason to put that fixed width?

Comment: i want to use full page !! use all of the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme is mobile first, you have 3 breakpoints:

```
/* here the mobile */

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
 /* tablet */
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
 /* laptop */
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
 /* bigger screens */
}
```

This are the rules defined in your theme, the best solution would be to modify all of them in order to fit you needs, but you have to consider that the '.container' class is assigned to several elements.

The quick fix is to modify your rule in this way:

```
.container {
  /* width: 1340px; */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response sir .
But why didnt you add any media query ? is it because it was already in my css?
Thanks

Comment: Done , :) i edited my comment Can u please tell me .

Comment: with `width:100%` you always use the 100% of you space as you asked, but if you modify everything according the `media-query`as I suggest, the result will be better

Answer (score 0):

Adding a fixed width certainly does not make your web site responsive. There's much more to it.

First, remove this style that breaks your site's responsiveness:

```
.container {
    width: 1340px;
}
```

The reason that it breaks responsiveness is that you applied a rule to .container and did not attach it to a media query that sets its' width for a desktop screen size.
So if you want your site to be 1340px wide on desktop screens, instead you could add it like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1370px) {
    .container {
        width: 1340px;
    }
}
```

Note the the `min-width` value could be modified, but it's assuming 15px padding on each side, so it makes sense (1340 + 15 + 15 = 1370).

Another important issue is *where* you place your CSS rule. It should cascade in an order that makes sense - from the general rule to the specific rule, and becuase your rule was placed at the bottom, it was overriding the width for all screen sizes and made it non-responsive.